The link of the zero set of the polynomial $f(z_1,z_2)=z_1^p+z_2^q$ at the origin
Let $p,q\geq 2$ be relatively prime integers and consider the polynomial $f(z_1,z_2)=z_1^p+z_2^q$. For small $\epsilon >0$, let $K$ denote the intersection $f^{-1}(0)\cap S_\epsilon \subset \Bbb C^2$, where $S_\epsilon$ is the $3$-sphere centered at the origin with radius $\epsilon$. Then $|z_1|$ and $|z_2|$ are constant on $K$; let $\xi=|z_1|$ and $\eta=|z_2|$.  In the introduction of Milnor's book Singular Points of Complex Hypersurfaces, it is asserted that $K$ consists of all pairs $(\xi e^{qi\theta}, \eta e^{pi\theta+\pi i /q})$, where $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. It is clear that $K$ contains all such pairs, but the converse does not seem obvious. How can we show that $K$ consists of such pairs?
My attempt: Let $(z_1,z_2)\in K$. Let $\alpha$ be the unique real number in $[0,2\pi)$ such that $z_1^p=-z_2^q=\xi^pe^{i\alpha}(=\eta^qe^{i\alpha})$. Then there is a unique $k\in \{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$ and  a unique $\ell \in \{0,1,\dots,q-1\}$ such that $z_1=\xi e^{i(\alpha+2k\pi)/p}$ and $z_2=\eta e^{i(\alpha+\pi+2\ell \pi)/q}$. Now if $z_1=\xi e^{qi\theta}$ with $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, then $\theta$ must equal $$\frac{\alpha+2k\pi}{pq}+\frac{2k'\pi}{q} $$
for some $k'\in \{0,1,\dots,q-1\}$, and similarly if $z_2=\eta e^{pi\theta+\pi i/q}$ then $\theta$ must equal $$\frac{\alpha+2\ell \pi}{pq} +\frac{2\ell' \pi}{p} $$
for some $\ell'\in\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$. Now the question reduces to the following question: Do there exist $k'\in \{0,1,\dots,q-1\}$ and $\ell'\in\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$ such that $k+pk'=\ell+q\ell'$? But I cannot see answer this.

Hint: The fact that $p$ and $q$ are coprime means that there exist integers $m$ and $n$ with $mp+nq=1$. (Maybe intuitively easier: $p$ is invertible mod $q$, and your last equation written mod $q$ is $pk' = l-k$...)

@LukasGeyer Thanks. It shows that there exists $k'\in {0,1,\dots,q-1}$ such that $pk'\equiv \ell-k \mod q$, so $pk'+k=\ell+\ell'q$ for some $\ell'\in \mathbb{Z}$. But can we assure here that $0\leq \ell' \leq p-1$?
